# Should dimensions with low reliability be omitted from EFA?

Tags: factor-analysis, dimensionality-reduction, reliability, intraclass-correlation

A set of items were rated on 25 dimensions by 85 participants. I've computed the ICCs on each dimension and they are all good (> .75) except one dimension which is moderate (.69) and one that is bad (.39).

I am planning to run an EFA on these 25 dimensions. Should I omit the "bad" dimension from my EFA? What about the dimension with a moderate ICC?

Comment: Could you give more context on what is your goal?

Comment: @Kuku I am interested in interpreting the resulting factor solution. I would then like to use the factor scores for each item in a subsequent analysis.